# Blog Page Redirects To Homepage

Tags: wordpress

My Blog Page keeps redirecting to my Static Homepage.

1. Front Page = Home
2. Post Page = Blog
3. Permalink: Post Name (ticked)
4. Blog Page = Default Template

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /demo/my-wordpress/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /demo/my-wordpress/index.php [L]
   </IfModule>

   # END WordPress
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

renamed my php file from home.php to homepage.php, i didn't know that the word "home" is a reserved word for template files.. that's why its redirecting to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your permalink, and also reading settings in the admin? I have had quite a few problems in the past with this myself. Double check which page you have setup as your "Front Page", and also your "Posts Page"

It could be your blog page is set as you "Front Page"

Comment: permalink checked, readings settings checked.. still no luck.

Comment: make a backup of your .htaccess file locally and delete it off the server. Then re-enable your permalinks, see if this works